# How do I set compound arithmetical-conditional value at table creation?

Tags: mysql

Struggling with syntax.  I wish to create a table with the following statement as its value and cannot find any resource addressing my issue at this point.  Here is the code I am trying to implement.

```
CREATE TABLE Order(
**other code omitted**
OrderTotal numeric(CASE 
WHEN Quality = 'basic' THEN Quantity*10/100
WHEN Quality = 'medium' THEN Quantity*15/100
ELSE Quantity*20/100),
**other code omitted**
)
```

I hope I am not too far off - thanks in advance for any help and information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL 5.7 you can accomplish this using a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Order` (
  Quality varchar(50),
  Quantity int,
  OrderTotal numeric AS (CASE 
WHEN Quality = 'basic' THEN Quantity*10/100
WHEN Quality = 'medium' THEN Quantity*15/100
ELSE Quantity*20/100 END)
);
```

Older versions of MySQL do not support generated columns, but you could create a view to mimic that functionality:

```
CREATE TABLE `Order` (
  Quality varchar(50),
  Quantity int
);

CREATE VIEW v_order as 
select Quality,Quantity,
(CASE 
WHEN Quality = 'basic' THEN Quantity*10/100
WHEN Quality = 'medium' THEN Quantity*15/100
ELSE Quantity*20/100 END) as OrderTotal
from `Order`;
```

Comment: Many thanks Ike, pretty sure we use 5.7 and if not I will have to do the calculation PHP - in any case I have not been able to test it as I cannot make the create table order work due to an elusive syntax error 1024 (42000) which I cannot find for the life of me.

Comment: The word "order" is a reserved word in MySQL, so you need to surround it with backticks if you use it as a table or column name. Look at my answer for examples. I recommend you change the table name (if you can) to something that is not a reserved word.